# BufferedReader перестает читать строчки

Tags: android, java, android-asynctask

Доброго времени суток. Имеется следующий класс (AsyncTask) для парсинга комментариев со страницы:

```
public class EntryCommentsParseTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>> {

ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> tmpData;
HashMap<String, Object> tmpMap;
HttpClient httpClient;
String tmpline;

@Override
protected ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> doInBackground(String... postUrl) {
    tmpData = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(postUrl[0]);
    String commentHtml = "";
    boolean startParseCode = false;
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        while ((tmpline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(tmpline.indexOf("<!-- </body> -->") != -1)
                break;
            if(tmpline.indexOf("<div class=\"message_l\"><img") != -1) 
                startParseCode = true;
            if(startParseCode)
                commentHtml += tmpline;
            if(commentHtml.indexOf("<div id=\"conts") != -1 && commentHtml.indexOf("</div>") != -1) {
                parseComment(commentHtml); //вырезал реализацию, она тут не нужна
                commentHtml = "";
                startParseCode = false;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tmpData;
}
}
```

На какой-то строке перестает считывать (часто вижу в конце логов (вывожу на экран tmpline)

```
<div class="side_left">
<!--U1CLEFTER1Z--><!--block1-->
```

Иногда после этих строк выводит

```
ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x40041000 size:4096
ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x553ff000 size:1536000
ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4ff18000 size:4096
ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x568b1000 size:1536000
ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x529d8000 size:4096
```

А после этого продолжает считывать строки. Но опять же повторюсь, продолжает читать редко, а из-за незаконченной задачи программа перестает выполнять другие задачи (AsyncTask). В чем проблема?

Comment: О, парсинг HTML вручную! Месье знает толк в извращениях.

Comment: А вы сомневались?  
p.s. Базовый API сайта не позволяет выводить комментарии, так что приходится как-то выкручиваться))

Comment: @PhoEn-X: В коде на взгляд неспециалиста по андроиду (то есть, меня) ничего криминального не видно. Ищите ошибку где-то ещё. Попробуйте, например, закомментировать вызов `parseComment` и посмотреть, будет ли зависать.

Кстати, может быть, просто сервер не отдаёт строки? Или сливает всё в одну большую строку?

Comment: С сервером, вроде бы, все в порядке. По крайней мере, я еще так чат парсил, там все адекватно работает. Не думаю, что дело в методе parseComment(). До вызова этого метода еще не доходит, там куча кода должна пройти через BufferedReader.

Comment: @PhoEn-X: Хм. Но всё же, попробуйте повыкидывать всё, что только можно. Попробуйте, например, тупо выводить каждую прочитанную строку в лог без разбора и анализа (но с timestamp'ом). Чем меньше кода, тем легче отлаживать. Вот и увидим, проблема с `BufferedReader`'ом или после него.

Comment: @VladD, сделано, все равно перестает считывать. Видимо сервер виноват.

Comment: @VladD, если и идет, то как мне это узнать? Через статус ответа сервера? Так я в Debug'е вижу response -> statusline -> statusCode = 200
Получается с ответом сервера все в порядке.

Comment: @PhoEn-X: ну, читайте ответ сервера не через `InputStreamReader`.

    while ((c = is.read()) != -1) { /* log c with timestamp */ }

Answer (score 1):

Постоянно твержу одно и то же. Сначала отладьте метод/способ/алгоритм без `AsyncTask`! И только потом "заводите" его под `AsyncTask`. Отладка под `AsyncTask`'ом удовольствие ниже среднего (что и видно в данном примере).

Comment: Сделано  
    
    <div class="content_all">
Вот и повисло на теге, как и в AsyncTask'е. Ровным счетом ничего не изменилось((

Comment: Ну вот теперь берем отладчик и вперед - выясняем почему именно в этом месте

Comment: у меня там одна строка  
    
    Log.d("myLogs", tmpline);
Отладчик ничего не скажет толкового в данном случае.

Comment: @PhoEn-X а ты попробуй... Посмотри значение переменных в стеке, поизучай структуру класса потока `Reader`

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, от отладчика, как от козла молока... Вообще не помогает. Запускаю без отладчика - висит. Запускаю с отладчиком - работает. Вообще же не поймешь в чем дело...

Comment: Это означает, что во входном потоке нет строки. Вернее нет признака окончания строки. Как известно, стандарт HTML может работать и без разделения текста на строки. То есть весь HTML вытянут в одну строку (например) или же где-то у вас в тексте есть бинарные символы об которые запинается ридер

Comment: То есть весь HTML вытянут в одну строку
имеются символы переноса строки, тем более что на первом устройстве считывает то же самое, но на месте не стоит, а читает дальше
    
    или же где-то у вас в тексте есть бинарные символы об которые запинается ридер
Опять-же, на первом устройстве, да и в редких случаях работы второго устройства, при загрузке одной и той же страницы все работает... Ерунда какая-то получается. Мне кажется, что без бубна тут не обойтись.